# Read secrets from Azure Key Vault using Managed Identity in PowerShell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I am using the below link to read the secrets from Azure Key Vault using Managed Identity in PowerShell script.

**Link:** *https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-ua-arm*

**PowerShell Script**

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&client_id=<%ManagedIdentitiesClientId%>&resource=https://management.azure.com/' -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"}
$content = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$ArmToken = $content.access_token
Write-Output $ArmToken
```

**When I run this script on VDI, I am getting the below Error:-**

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/i ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
 
ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At line:2 char:32
+ $content = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

Seems I am not able to connect to http://169.254.169.254/ URL.

Is there any alternative approach or any help is really appreciated.

Comment: `169.254` is definitely not the address of any internet endpoint

Comment: OK I see it's in the code sample.... interesting. Is this being execute inside an Azure VM? It's a little easier for Powershell to use the MI in Azure Automation if you want to take that route

Comment: Where are you running this script from ?

Comment: I am running this script on VDI

Comment: Are you running this script inside in the VM for which user assigned managed identity is created? I am able to run the script successfully inside my Azure VM

Comment: No. I am not running this script in Azure VM. I am running this script in VDI.

Comment: The documentation you are following is for the user managed identity for Azure VM, not VDI

Comment: Anyway, I will be running this script using azure CD only. Is this will on azure CD? Any help...

Comment: If your service connection have access to Azure Key Vault, you can use variable groups or key vault task to retrieve secrets

Comment: Yes, We have access to Azure Key Vault. Can you please provide me the links.. It would be very helpful....

Comment: I added the answer for how to use  Azure Key Vault secrets in Azure Devops Pipelines

Answer (score 0):

You can use Variable Groups in Azure DevOps Pipelines to use Key Vault secrets in Pipelines

Go to your DevOps project --> Select Pipelines --> Click on Library --> New Variable Group

Enable Link Secrets from an Azure Key Vault as variables. Select your service connection and the key vault.

Make sure to have an access policy for your service connection to GET and LIST secrets

[image]

Under Variables, click on Add and select the secrets you want to use in your pipelines. Click on save

Click on Pipeline permissions and give access to your pipelines.

Now, you can use these variables in your CD pipeline

**Reference**: [Integrate and get Azure Key Vault Secrets in your DevOps pipelines (zimmergren.net)](https://zimmergren.net/using-azure-key-vault-secrets-from-azure-devops-pipeline/)

Comment: Thank you so much @RamaraoAdapa-MT. Let me try this and will come back.

Comment: Did you get a chance to test this?

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to http://169.254.169.254 from a VM that has System-Assigned identity enabled. This is a private endpoint accessible only from the VM itself.

Here's the tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-nonaad

Go to Azure portal, Key Vault has "Access policy" screen where you must grant the Secret 'get' permission to the VMs system-assigned identity.

```
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fvault.azure.net' -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"}

$KeyVaultToken = $Response.access_token

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://${KeyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/secrets/${SecretName}?api-version=2016-10-01" -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $KeyVaultToken"}
```